# Inplementing boolean values

Tags: java

I am trying to make the code more efficient, but don't know how to apply it in my code. What I have in mind is changing the integers `insideIsGreater` and `outsideIsGreater` into boolean values. The only problem after that is that I do not know where to begin changing my code. Does anyone care to help?

```
int amountPassed = 0;
int insideIsGreater = 0;
int outsideIsGreater = 0;

for (Measurement measurement : measurements) {

    double outsideTemp = measurement.getOutsideTemp();  // gets the outside temperature
    double insideTemp = measurement.getInsideTemp();    // gets the inside temperature

    if (outsideTemp > insideTemp) {
        if (outsideIsGreater == 0) {
            amountPassed++;
            outsideIsGreater += 1;
            insideIsGreater = 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (insideTemp > outsideTemp) {
            if (insideIsGreater == 0) {
                amountPassed++;
                insideIsGreater += 1;
                outsideIsGreater = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks like the values are only ever 0 or 1. So maybe represent those as false and true respectively? (It's not clear what your code is actually trying to achieve, to be honest... editing your question to explain that would probably help us to give better advice.)

Comment: Start with reading on primitive types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html. Understand that `boolean` types can only have two values: `true` and `false` (and not `1` and `0`). So change the type of `insideIsGreater` to boolean, then change its values to true/false. Done.

Comment: _I am trying to make the code more efficient_ Do you mean there is a performance issue? If yes, have you used a profiler to prove those `if` blocks are the bottleneck?  Is `Measurement` a POJO or does it make API calls, read from a file, or do some other relatively time consuming processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int amountPassed = 0;
boolean isInsideIsGreater = false;
boolean isOutsideIsGreater = false;

for (Measurement measurement : measurements) {
    double outsideTemp = measurement.getOutsideTemp();  // gets the outside temperature
    double insideTemp = measurement.getInsideTemp();    // gets the inside temperature
        
    if (outsideTemp > insideTemp) {
        if (!isOutsideIsGreater) {
            amountPassed++;
        }
        isOutsideIsGreater = true;
        isInsideIsGreater = false;
    } else if (insideTemp > outsideTemp) {
        if (!isInsideIsGreater) {
            amountPassed++;
        }
        isInsideIsGreater = true;
        isOutsideIsGreater = false;
    } else {    // temperature is same
        isInsideIsGreater = false;
        isOutsideIsGreater = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it as follows:

```java
int amountPassed = 0;
boolean insideTemperatureIsGreaterThanOutside = false;

for (Measurement measurement : measurements) {

    double outsideTemp = measurement.getOutsideTemp();  // gets the outside temperature
    double insideTemp = measurement.getInsideTemp();    // gets the inside temperature

    if (insideTemp > outsideTemp) {
        amountPassed++;
        insideTemperatureIsGreaterThanOutside = true;
    }
}
```

Still, I have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve with `insideIsGreater` and `outsideIsGreater` (which can be unified into a single `insideTemperatureIsGreaterThanOutside` boolean).

Answer (score 0):

When you change something about a variable (such as its type), your first and immediate concern is usually at places where you set values of these variables and where you read values of these variables. So examine those places.

At places where `insideIsGreater` and `outsideIsGreater` is being set, you have to change to set boolean values `true` or `false` instead of an integer.

At places where they are being read, you need to change so that the operations (such as comparison) is done suitably with another operand.